# What would be the answer to this problem?

Tags: java

Im confused about this question:

Consider the following method. What is the value of recur("mouse", 2)?

```
 public static String recur(String str, int n)
 {
 if(n >= str.length())
 {
      return str;
 }

 return str + recur(str.substring(n), n + 2);
 }
```

I think the value would be "use" since the method recurs with recur(use,4), causing it to return use but im not sure if it would stop at that first return causing it to give use or if it would go to the second return statement.

Comment: Hint: You can answer such questions by simply running the code.

Comment: Yep.  It returns `mouseuse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let's trace `recur("mouse", 2)`:

1. Is 2 ≥ 5? No.
2. Return `"mouse" + recur("use", 4)`.

Let's trace `recur("use", 4)`:

1. Is 4 ≥ 3? Yes.
2. Return `"use"`.

So, going back to `recur("mouse", 2)`, we have it returning:

- `"mouse" + recur("use", 4)`
- `"mouse" + "use"`
- `"mouseuse"`

Answer (score 0):

The method would return `mouseuse`.

`recur("mouse", 2)` will first return `mouse`, plus `recur("use", 4)` (`use` is because `"mouse".substring(2)` returns `use`).

`recur("use", 4)` will return `use`, as `4 >= str.length()` and `str.length()` equals 3. Since this is satisfied, it will return the `str` itself, which is `use`.

So, `recur("use", 4)` returns `use`. Concatenate that with `mouse`, you get `mouseuse`.